# Prepared statement for Select SQL with Connection Pooling

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

Is it good practice to use Prepared statement for `SELECT SQL` with connection pooling. (In my case I use Tomcat JDBC connection pool).

Does it add any advantage(speed ups) or it will add overhead for maintaining the Prepared Statements, connections and keep them alive or track whether closed  as Pooled connections are maintained internally and they get closed according to different settings [as specified here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementCache).

I am using `DataSource` to get connection, Database is MariaDB.

While reading various [posts](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/preparestatement-object-example.htm), [documentations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and examples most of `Prepared Statement` have been built using `INSERT` or `UPDATE` queries. Does it points that for `SELECT` it will not add any advantage?

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement` when you have dynamic queries.

Comment: Is you question about connection pooling or prepared statements?

Comment: @shmosel Prepared Statements on Pooled Connections

Comment: @RC Dynamic Queries no idea what they actually mean

Comment: The main point of using prepared statement is not performance. That's a nice side effect. The main point is to be able to pass parameters, safely, of the correct type (i.e. Date, Timestamp, String, Int, etc.) to the query. Of course you should use prepared statements. Regarding performance, databases, drivers, and pools can all have caches. If they have, your code will be faster. If none does, it won't be significantly slower than withb a Statement, but will still be safer and more robust.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094529/prepared-statements-along-with-connection-pooling and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889401/preparedstatement-pool-with-connection-pool

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB/MySQL prepared statements do not have any advantages when it comes to query parsing / optimizing, the query plan is not preserved as on some other SQL databases.

They do have a performance advantage when it comes to transferring result sets as column values can be transfered in binary form and get stored into result variables right away. With classic non-prepared statements all result fields are converted to textual form on the server side. This adds processing time on the server side, leads to more bytes having to be transfered over the wire, and depending on your application needs the client side may need to convert values back from textual to binary form (e.g. for integer and float values).

The other reason for using prepared statements, as also noted in the previous comments, is that it is a reliable way to prevent SQL injection, and that applies to SELECT as well as INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE

Answer (score 1):

It's good to use `PreparedStatement` if you can:

- Prevent SQLInjection
- Abstract Date/Time representation
- Deal with `Charset` conversions
- Readability (you see one string with full SQL)
- As the SQL stays constant (with ?) the database might cache the plan and doesn't have to reparse

In case of `SELECT` the main focus of cause lies with the parameters passed into the `WHERE` condition.

As for performance: This may depend - but I've never experienced `PreparedStatement`s to be significantly worse than simple `Statement`s - if coded correct of cause.

The fact that you're **pooling** connections doesn't add much to this. The concept of somehow *"preparing all the statements you're going to need on that connection for later"* is not how PreparedStatments are meant to be used. It's perfectly fine to prepare the same tiny Statement over and over and over - altough if faced with a loop of `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s it would be wise to reuse PreparedStatement and/or batch the `INSERT`s

Comment: How does it "Deal with Charset conversions"?

Comment: By supporting NVARCHAR as well as Varchar setters - you'll have a hard time coding correctly intonthe string passed into the Statement otherwise

Comment: In MariaDB/MySQL, `NVARCHAR` is merely a synonym for `VARCHAR`.  Where does the charset come from?

Comment: (I guess I don't know enough Jdbc to understand what you are telling me.)

Comment: In this case (MariaDB) that argument might not be valid then.